# Excel - how to find wildcard string from large list

Tags: excel, string, search, excel-formula

My data table consists of a) index numbers and b) strings associated with those index numbers. In my template, a user would input an index number and the string associated with that index number would show.

For example

```
1    Bag
1    Catsgsg
1    Dogs
1    oygg
2    Stackoverflow
2    tacks
2    Binoculars
2    all
.
.
.
1000   Bonobos
1000   Canopy
1000   Ascot
```

If a user inputs the number 1000, how can I pull the word bonobos knowing that there's a b word but not the actual word? How can I fix my array formula to work for wildcards?

```
=INDEX(Partners!$D$2:$D$2227,MATCH(1,(Partners!$A$2:$A$2227=number)*(Partners!$C$2:$C$2227="b *"),0))
```

EDIT: I was able to tweak callum's solution and have the formula account for multiple wildcard strings.

```
=INDEX(Partners!$D$2:$D$2227,MATCH(1,IFERROR(SEARCH(num&"A*",Partners!$A$2:$A$2227&Partners!$D$2:$D$2227),0)+IFERROR(SEARCH(num&"B*",Partners!$A$2:$A$2227&Partners!$D$2:$D$2227),0)+IFERROR(SEARCH(num&"C*",Partners!$A$2:$A$2227&Partners!$D$2:$D$2227),0),0))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only specific functions accept wildcards so you will need to use one of them if you want to use the `*` wildcard. `SEARCH` is one example:

```
=INDEX(Partners!$D$2:$D$2227,MATCH(1,IFERROR(SEARCH(number&"b*",Partners!$A$2:$A$2227&Partners!$B$2:$B$2227),0),0))
```

Or, you can just avoid the wildcard altogether:

```
=INDEX(Partners!$D$2:$D$2227,MATCH(number&"b",Partners!$A$2:$A$2227&LEFT(Partners!$B$2:$B$2227,1),0))
```

*both entered as array formulae (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)*

Comment: Thanks callum, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: is it possible to search for an array of wildcards? for example, if you want any words that start with a b, c or d... can you do search(number&{"b*", "c*", "d*"},......)

Comment: Hi @excelmonkey93, happy to help. Unfortunately the search function couldn't achieve that but it's probably doable by some other complicated formula. I'd probably save myself time and have separate formulas for each search value b,c,... etc

Comment: thanks, I was able to figure it out. edited post with solution

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
=INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, A:A)))/((A$1:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, A:A))=E6)*(LEFT(B$1:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99, A:A)), 1)=F6)), 1))
```

In the following supplied sample image, I have changed your **B** to a **C** in order to demonstrate that the formula is not simply returning the first **1000** found.

[image]