# Excel - finding string using array of wildcards

Tags: excel, search

This is a follow-up to an earlier question I posted. [Excel - how to find wildcard string from large list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058847/excel-how-to-find-wildcard-string-from-large-list/43058990#43058990)

Callum suggested the following array formula to find the desired string from my data table.

I know in Excel it's possible to do sumifs(range,criteria_range,{"criteria","criteria1",....}). Is it possible to do change the below formula so that it does something similar, and takes an array of wildcards? e.g. search(10&{"b*","c*","d*"},....). I don't think search function would work, maybe countifs ...

```
=INDEX(Partners!$D$2:$D$2227,MATCH(1,IFERROR(SEARCH(10&"b*",Partners!$A$2:$A$2227&Partners!$B$2:$B$2227),0),0))
```